# I am getting outofbound error while removing from the ArrayList even the size of the arraylist is correct

Tags: java

this is the way I am adding the data to the arrayList

```
System.out.println("please select part/s (-1 for return to the main menu)");

//array to store multiple inputs
String[] part = scanner.nextLine().split(",");

//adding customer computer parts to its order
for (int k = 0; k < part.length; k++) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(part[k]) == -1) {
       //thats just to break the loop but its not creating any problem
        bool = false;
    } else {
        os.ord.addComputerPart(os.computerParts.get(Integer.parseInt(part[k])));
    }
}
```

here is the method to add the inputs the ArrayList

```
public void addComputerPart(ComputerPart computerpart ){
    parts.add(computerpart);
    totalPrice += computerpart.getPrice();
}
```

Now here is the method to remove the data from the arrayList

```
//os is the class object and ord is the order class object which is the seperate class and order class contains the parts arraylist 
System.out.println( os.ord.getParts().size());

//printing the information about the customer and the order
System.out.println("here is the summary of your current order");

System.out.println(os.ord);

Scanner scxx = new Scanner(System.in);

//using the array to take more than one inputs
System.out.println("Please select part/s to be removed from the order (-1 for return to the main menu)");
String[] part = scxx.nextLine().split(",");

//deleting customer computer parts from  its order                                    
for (int k = 0; k < part.length; k++) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(part[k]) == -1) {
       delete = false;
    } else {
       os.ord.removeComputerPart(Integer.parseInt(part[k]));
    }
}
```

Now in again order class I have a method to remove the data from the arrayList which removes the data

```
public void removeComputerPart(int index){
    parts.remove(index);
    totalPrice-= parts.get(index).getPrice();
}
```

Now problem is that when i remove the element from the arraylist it give me indexoutofbound error

```
4 --> as u can see that while printing the size of the arraylist i am getting 4 elements but when i delete the 4th element it gives me error 
here is the summary of your current order

(0): Product ID : INTCPU94496  Brand : INT  Model : 9700K  Price : 462.0  Core : i7
  Socket : Intel
not compatible with : 
(1): Product ID : INTCPU12673  Brand : INT  Model : 9700F  Price : 396.0  Core : i7
  Socket : Intel
not compatible with : 
(2): Product ID : INTCPU72675  Brand : INT  Model : 9900K  Price : 591.0  Core : i9
  Socket : Intel
not compatible with : 
(3): Product ID : AMDCPU54823  Brand : AMD  Model : Ryzen 2200  Price : 200.0  Core : 4
  Socket : AMD
not compatible with : 

Order Id : O104181 Total Price : $1649.0
 Member customer discount : $82.45 total price after discount : $1566.55
Please select part/s to be removed from the order (-1 for return to the main menu)
3

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
```

Comment: `totalPrice-= parts.get(index).getPrice();` you need to do this _before_ removing the object. Otherwise you get a crash if you remove the last object or you deduct the wrong price for any other object removed. Also, you should learn to debug your program to find this kind of issue yourself.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson u mean debugging using breakpoints?

Comment: @Madhav Debugging with either break points or `System.out.println()` are both fine. In this case, you should look at the rest of the stack trace that you didn't post here and find where it mentions a line in your own code. Add some output just before that line to determine why it is crashing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Inside `removeComputerPart()` method *first deduct the price of part* then *remove that parts* from the list. **removeComputerPart()** method will be as follows-

```
public void removeComputerPart(int index){
    totalPrice-= parts.get(index).getPrice();   // first line
    parts.remove(index);                        // second line
}
```